# Local Load Testing: The load test results database could not be opened

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, load-testing

I am creating some Load tests using VS2012. I can run the tests using a StorageType of "None", but when I change this to a StorageType of "Database" I get the dreaded error

> The load test results database could not be opened.  Check that the
>   load test results database specified by the connect string for your
>   test controller (or local machine) specifies a database that contains
>   the load test schema and that is currently available.  For more
>   information, see the Visual Studio help topic 'About the Load Test
>   Results Store'.   The connection error was: An error occurred while
>   attempting to create the load test results repository schema: To
>   create the database 'LoadTest2010' your user account must have the
>   either the SQL Server 'sysadmin' role or both the 'serveradmin' and
>   'dbcreator' roles

I have created a database on a non local copy of SQL called LoadTest. When I test the connection from the SQL Tracing Connect String dialog I get a success.

I have created a SQL user that has the Server Roles of dbcreator, public, serveradmin and sysadmin. The user has a User Mapping to the LoadTest2010 database that was created from the loadtestresultsrepository.sql in the VS2012 IDE directory. On the database the user has the Database role memberships db_accessadmin, db_datareader, db_datawriter, db_owner.
In the Owned Schemas i ticked on the db_datareader, db_datawriter, db_owner and db_securityadmin howver these have now gone to a blue square instead of a tick when displayed.

So what's going on? Is Visual studio trying to create the database or is something else the issue?

I am not using TestControllers or TestAgents I am simply using a local run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was simple. I was setting up the connection string in the "SQL Tracing Connect String" instead of clicking the little "Manage Test Controller" icon at the top of my load test window and setting up the connection string from there.

Now I'm off to remove some of those superfluous permissions I created on that SQL user :)

**Edit:**

[image]

The SQL Connection String is *NOT* stored in the loadtest files. The setting seems to be PC specific so I had to change it on the build server - in one loadtest file (address.loadtest) as shown, then all the other loadtests adopt the same connection string.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and had this error as well, but for a different reason. It's not entirely clear when setting up a load test for the first time that it will attempt to save the results to a database by default. I didn't realize it was trying to save results to a database until I got the error on my first run attempt. Furthermore, in the load test wizard, there is no screen to configure the database settings or create the database schema for that matter.

I found this article on MSDN which helped me solve the problem.

**How to: Create a Load Test Results Repository Using SQL**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182600%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Basically, it explains that you first need to run a script to create the load test repository schema. Once this is in place on your SQL instance is (it could be anywhere you like), then you can point your load test to this database and save your results there.

Comment: Thanks for the article link. In my case, i ended up opening my local sqlexpress db instance in sql management studio. Next, I opened and ran %programfiles(x86)%\microsoft visual studio 14.0\common7\ide\loadtestresultsrepository.sql, which created a LoadTest2010 database for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me after I had set database connections and all the test results was still not writing to the database.

I forgot to change my storage type in the properties section of the runsettings.
The property is called 'Storage Type'

Storage Type : change it from None to Database